# Ruby: find audio duration of file, when having its "string buffer"

Tags: ruby, audio, mp3

I got the string data of a mp3 file (what you'll get when you execute `File.read "1.mp3"`).

I found some ways to fetch mp3 audio duration when I have a file, but now I have only a file string content. I can think about a workaround of creating a temp file from the string I got, and then use a library that knows how to fetch the duration.

Do you know a way I can avoid this tempfile creation and fetch the duration directly from the file data string?

Comment: Well, look how that library does it. Maybe you can even make it accept an `IO` instead of filename.

Answer (score 0):

I found [ruby-audioinfo](https://github.com/moumar/ruby-audioinfo) or [taglib-ruby](http://robinst.github.io/taglib-ruby/). You want get duration, artist, title, etc... (these gems utilize metadata).